# Intel HD Graphics 530 performance issue + flickering

Tags: windows-10, drivers, performance, integrated-graphics

A few days ago I bought an ASUS N552VX laptop which has Intel HD 530 Graphics plus a dedicated NVIDIA GeForce 950M and a 4K screen, running Windows 10 Pro version 1511 Build 10586 with the Intel HD 530 driver version 10.18.15.4281.

1- The screen flickers occasionally, with the bottom part of the screen going blank or "flickering" for a frame or two when anything with animation happens: something moves on the desktop, Task View is invoked, a menu opens, etc.

2-The desktop performance of the Intel graphics is very bad. Opening the Windows Task View, you can see the few open windows move with a slow animation and in 3 to 4 frames into their position.

Changing the resolution to Full HD solves both problems. However, if the laptop display is in Full HD and a second display is connected through HDMI, the problem returns (my guess is total resolution goes above 1920x1080, that's why).

The latest official 15.40.10.4300 Intel driver didn't solve anything. The latest Beta driver 15.40.18.4380 however got rid of the flickering, but the slow desktop performance above Full HD is still there.

1-Those with the same hardware configuration: have you experienced the same issue, or is it just my laptop?

2-Since I got this laptop recently and I have 7 days to test it, I am wondering if the problem is with the hardware or just driver related and whether I should ask for a replacement.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: report it to Intel in their forums. We can't code any drivers that fix your issues.

Comment: I asked 2 very specific questions.

Comment: both are driver related. All Intel HD 5xx chips have massive driver issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current driver: 20.19.15.4474 (6/13/2016)

After a number of driver updates the performance issue is still there and at this point I'm not sure if Intel HD 530 is powerful enough to run a 4K display smoothly. Works well enough, but the GPU certainly struggles with animating multiple windows on multiple displays.

Flickering however is completely gone.